# Empty {{ MEDIA_URL }} tag, caused by transitioning from Django 1.7.2 to 1.8

Tags: python, django

I recently upgraded from Django 1.7.2 to 1.8 and ran into some issues, particularly with rendering the {{MEDIA_URL}} tag, it shows up as empty. I've been looking for hours on what might be causing this problem but am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated

In my urls.py I added

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tala_app/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tala_app/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My static files seem to work fine however.

and in my views.py I return as:

```
return render(request, 'browse.html', context)
```

and attempted to use:

```
return render_to_response('test.html', context, 
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

where context is a context dictionary, but none have been successful so far.

If I set a link as /media/{{path-to-img}} instead of {{MEDIA_URL}}{{path-to-img}} then it works fine.

I feel as if I'm missing something really obvious but can't figure out what

Thanks

P.S: If there is anything else that is important from transitioning from 1.7.2 to 1.8, please let me know (I have read the backward-incompatibility-changes on their website, or at least as much as I could)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upgrade of Django 1.8 introduce new settings for Templates. Instead of using:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"main_app.context_processor.NavbarContext",)
```

You should use:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

The Django documentation says:

> All existing template-related settings were deprecated

Update your Templates setting and you will be fine.
For more information, please see: [Upgrading templates to Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/)